# Need Script for Deploying KeePass to my Users Share Drives

Tags: windows, share, keepass

I'm looking for a script for copying the KeePass folder from a Network Share to my Staffs' individual Personal Network Share Drives.
I also want a shortcut to keepass.exe sent to their (windows) desktops.

Any help would be appreciated. I am not a scripting expert by any means.

I tried modifying an old script from before our servers migrated, but that has not worked. I think I need to start over with a fresh script.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what issues you had by [edit]ing the question?  As it stands your question is too broad.